# Put p value inside the input text field 2#

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, bootstrap-modal

I am facing small issues while trying to move value p inside the input text field (in second table).. 
I have 2 different table. First table have button and javascript. I have successfully passed value "Chemendon" and "Morning" to the second table with this format:

```
<p id="venue"></p>
<p id="session"></p>
```

Below the code button and javascript for first table

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="btn btn-avai btn-sm" type="button" onclick="addroom()" value="Available" />
</td>
  <script>
    function addroom() 
    { document.getElementById("venue").innerHTML = "Chemendon";
      document.getElementById("session").innerHTML = "Morning";
    }
  </script>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

second table only have input text field and p value where I want to move the p value inside input text field

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Venue/Facility" size="1"/>
<p id="venue"></p>
</td>
<td>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Session" size="1"/>
<p id="session"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

note. I have already asked this question before and 2 people have answered my question. but it is not work. so here I try to explain more details.

thanks, faizal.

Comment: just add `onblur` event to input box like `onblur="addroom()"`

Comment: You can't have multiple ids! (if both tables are on same page) Also, how you want to move p value, which event (click, mouseover....)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the specific ids to your input boxes like

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Venue/Facility" size="1" name="venue" id="venue_input" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Session" size="1" name="session" id="session_input" />
```

than you can use the below code

```
<script>
function addroom() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("venue").innerHTML = "Chemendon";
    document.getElementById("session").innerHTML = "Morning";
    document.getElementById("venue_input").value = document.getElementById("venue").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("session_input").value = document.getElementById("session").innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you know how to have an id for a paragraph element to assign values, why can't you try having an id for your input element,

```
<input id="tvenue" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Venue/Facility" size="1"/>
<input id="tsession" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Session" size="1"/>
```

and then have your javascript assign values to your input elements,

```
function addroom() 
{ document.getElementById("tvenue").value = "Chemendon";
  document.getElementById("tsession").value = "Morning";
}
```

Just a basic javascript stuff. isn't it? or am I missing something on your question?

Comment: Hi, just need adding code at the javascript.
@Suman Singh have fixed it. 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the input field and then the value of it `document.getElementById("venueInput").value` please check out this codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWWRxw